# How do I revert a 301 redirect from A to B, without causing an infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I accidentally made a 301 redirect from A to B, and want to revert it, do I then make another 301 redirect in the `.htaccess` at B that points back to A, or will that cause an infinite loop?

EDIT:
I control both A and B.

Comment: Remove the original one, and then add a new redirect to replace it.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I've removed the old one. I'm a bit lost as to where to point the new one, to not cause a loop.  I wan't it to go to the subfolder, where my wordpress site is located (A). B is another domain.

Comment: If you've removed the old `A --> B` redirect then antything you do will not inherently cause a loop (as far as I can understand from your description)

Comment: You should update your question and clarify what you control and what you don't control in terms of A , B, C etc

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429503/how-do-i-undo-the-effects-of-a-301-permanent-redirect-and-get-the-domain-to-poi anyway.